# Assign result of a dynamic sql statement containing COALESCE to a variable

Tags: exec, variable-assignment, dynamic-sql, coalesce, sp-executesql

I have a dynamic SQL statement built using COALESCE. I need the result from the execution of this dynamic sql statement to be assigned to a variable. I tried the following code but it is not assigning the output to the variable @result. When execution completes, exec displays the correct result but the output of "select @result" is always NULL

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @result int  


SELECT   @SQL = COALESCE('select '+ @SQL + CHAR(13) + ' + ' + CHAR(13),'' ) 
                       +
                       '(SELECT case when count(distinct ' + convert(varchar(10),object_id) + ' ) > 0 then 1 else 0 end from sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats 
                         WHERE object_id = '+convert(varchar(10),object_id)
                         +'AND last_user_update > dateadd(minute, -1, getdate()) 
                         )'                         
FROM sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats
WHERE object_id in (object_id('table1'),object_id('table2'))
AND database_id = db_id(db_name())

EXEC sp_executesql @SQL, N'@result int output', @result out 

select @result
```

Answer (score 1):

Following code helped me fix this issue.

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @result int  
DECLARE @parms nvarchar(1000)

SELECT   @SQL = COALESCE('select @cnt='+ @SQL + CHAR(13) + ' + ' + CHAR(13),'' ) 
                       +
                       '(SELECT case when count(distinct ' + convert(varchar(10),object_id) + ' ) > 0 then 1 else 0 end from sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats 
                         WHERE object_id = '+convert(varchar(10),object_id)
                         +'AND last_user_update > dateadd(minute, -1, getdate()) 
                        )'                          
FROM sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats
WHERE object_id in (object_id('table1'),object_id('table2'))
AND database_id = db_id(db_name())

SET @parms = N'@cnt int out'

EXEC sp_executesql @SQL, @parms, @cnt = @result out

select @result
```